# How to create a table containing all dates in a given year that are within a 7-day range of known dates (from a separate table)

Tags: postgresql

I have a table (holidays) containing all the holidays in a year:
[image]

I need to make a table (t1) where 1 column contains all the 365 days within a year, and another column 'description' containing a name of a holiday for all dates that are within a +/- 7 day range of a holiday, and 'None' for all dates that are outside of this range.

I was able to use generate_series to create the first-column (my_date: all 365 days within a year) and used a left-join to try to create the second column (description)

```
WITH all_dates AS
    SELECT my_date::date
    FROM generate_series('2020-01-01', '2020-12-31', '1 day'::interval) my_date)
 
SELECT  all_dates.my_date,
        holidays.description
FROM all_dates
LEFT JOIN holidays
        ON all_dates.my_date = holidays.holiday_date
```

To create the table below.

[image]

However, I need it to be such that 2020-01-02, 2020-01-02, ..., 2020-01-08 would have the description 'New Year's Day' as these dates are within a 7-day range of New Year's Day, and so forth for other days within a 7-day range of other holidays (e.g., rows for dates between 2020-12-18 to 2020-12-31 would have the description 'Christmas')

I'm also unsure about how to handle days that are within a 7-day range of more than one holiday (Father's Day and Independence Day have overlapping dates that are within a 7-day range). I need it to be such that there is only one row per day in 2020.

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like below.  You already have the ranges around the holidays, so use that in the join.  Then, use `distinct on` to restrict results to one per calendar date, and adjust the `order by` to keep the holiday you want.

```
with all_dates as (
  select my_date::date
    from generate_series('2020-01-01', 
                         '2020-12-31', '1 day'::interval) my_date
)
select distinct on (all_dates.my_date) 
       all_dates.my_date,
       holidays.description
  from all_dates
       left join holidays
         on all_dates.my_date 
              between holidays.holiday_date_min7
                  and holidays.holiday_date_plus7
 order by all_dates.my_date, 
          abs(all_dates.my_date - holidays.holiday_date), -- keep closest
          all_dates.my_date - holidays.holiday_date -- prefer upcoming holiday
```

Comment: There's no need for the CTE, just use `generate_series()` directly as a row source with appropriate aliases